# Python lambda calling Postgres function: not saving changes

Tags: python, postgresql, function

I have an AWS lambda, written in Python.

It calls a PL/PGSQL function in my database that should get a number from a database table, increment it and return the incremented value.

```
@staticmethod
def get_next_msg_id():
    query = "select <schema>.<function>();"
    db_conn = _db_engine.connect()
    cursor = db_conn.execute(text(query))
    message_id = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    cursor.close()
    db_conn.close()
    
    logger.debug(f"Next message id: {message_id}")
    
    return message_id
```

The database connectivity from the lambda to Postgres is provided by SQLAlchemy and an AWS RDS proxy.

The PL/PGSQL function looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION <schema>.<function>()
  RETURNS integer
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    new_sequence_value  INTEGER;
BEGIN
    -- Lock table.
    LOCK TABLE <schema>.<table> IN ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE;

    -- Increment; return the next number.
    UPDATE  <schema>.<table>
    AS      updated
    SET     sequence_value = (sequence_value + 1)
    RETURNING updated.sequence_value
        INTO new_sequence_value;

    RETURN new_sequence_value;
END
$function$
;
```

My understanding was that PL/PGSQL functions are "self encapsulating" and any changes should be saved as part of the implied transaction when the function is called (I've tried putting a "COMMIT" command in the function but Postgres won't allow it)

However, when I call the function repeatedly as I loop through a set of records in the Python code - via repeated calls to get_next_msg_id() - I can see that the value returned from the function is not incrementing. I have checked the database and the value in . is not being updated.

Example log output:

```
2020-12-21 13:42:33,599 - DEBUG - Next message id: 4559
2020-12-21 13:42:48,772 - DEBUG - Next message id: 4559
```

I can see no error messages when the call to the PL/PGSQL function is made.

Just wondered if anyone can see anything obviously wrong here. By the fact that I am calling the function - and it seems to be returning a value - I am confused as to why the value is not being updated. Is there some kind of caching going on?

I'm using Postgres version 11.9 and Python 3.7.9.

Many thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Are you wanting to increment in Python and commit back to Postgres? Or, do you want to do this soley with SQL using Python as a wrapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of changes were required.

Python code:

```
raw_connection = None
cur = None

try:
    raw_connection = _db_engine.raw_connection()
    cur = raw_connection.cursor()

    cur.execute(query)
    result = cur.fetchone()[0]

    # Ensure that commit is called so that changes are made/applied.
    raw_connection.commit()

    return result
except Exception as e:
    raise e
finally:
    if cur:
        cur.close()
    if raw_connection:
        raw_connection.close()
```

PL/PGSQL - replace LOCK TABLE with:

```
PERFORM   1
    FROM  <schema>.<table>
    FOR UPDATE;
```